# GET Requesting URL/Domain Name of Application

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys hope you can help me with this. I want to get the "Domain name" of the requesting application from my API. Example:

Requesting url:
http://myrequestor.com/

API /Application URL:
http://myapi.com/request/validate/

Now on my validate function whenever an external application request something from the API URL I would like to retrieve the Domain name of the requesting application. Its something like I would like to know if the domain name requesting for it is among the blacklisted application.

Any idea guys? sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: I think you are looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] - **But not always set, can be manipulated, and not reliable.** (Same goes for other HTTP headers)

```
<?php 
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)){
   //do your validation
   if (in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], $myBlacklistDomains)){
      //fail
   }
}
else{
   //fail?
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this but its not returning any use. Its just returning all details of the server from which the API URL is located. Well I guess I need to check my settings I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should use php's SERVER function. Have a look at this. [PHP SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP_REFERER in PHP.

The HTTP REFERER in PHP is stored in the $_SERVER super global, and can be referenced from anywhere in your PHP code like in the following example, which would simply write it out to the browser:

```
    <?php
        echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //Print the URL address from where user opens your link.
    ?>
```

Also check this link for more details :  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/